# Issues displaying div in center of parallax

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a a parallax component and I'm trying to display the text in the middle of the image. The horizontal alignment is fine but for the life of me I can't align it vertically.

I currently have my code set up as follows:

```
<template>
<div id="app">

    <div class="parallax">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Center this div</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</template>
```

This is the code in my scss file for the parallax

```
.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 750px;
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I've tried a few things with bootstrap as seen above, and a further "centered" class which can be seen below.

```
.center-item {
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;  /*Aligns vertically center */
    justify-content: center; /*Aligns horizontally center */
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```
    <div class="parallax">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h3 class="center-item">Center this div</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What would be the best way to display the  tag in the center of the parallax component? Not just centered at the top.

Comment: `.center-item` is never used, also using flexbox is really usefull to preform this type of styling, but you need to use it correctly to work. `diplay:flex` on a child will not style the child, but style the child of child, therefor. you should add the flexbox styling from `.center-item` to the `.parralax`

Comment: That's brilliant, adding the display: flex to the parralax has worked!!

Comment: yes, probably because you add flexbox styling to the child, and not the parent

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css:

```
.parallax {
    position: relative;
}
.mt-5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```